# @UnwrapValidatedValue and Spring LocalValidatorFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I try to to do some optional validation (hibernate validator 5.2.4.FINAL) within my spring project:

```
public class ExecutePaymentCardPresentRequestV2 {
    @Length(min = 6)
    @UnwrapValidatedValue
    private Optional<String> maskedTrack2 = Optional.empty();
    ...
}
```

And here is the Bean definition for my LocalValidatorBeanFactory:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

When I try to compile this usng "mvn clean install", I get the following error: ExecutePaymentCardPresentRequestV2.java:[21,5] The annotation @Length is disallowed for this data type.

I guess I need to change something in my LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean definition but I do not really know what. Can someone give me a hint?

Best,
Moritz